# java : How garbage collection works for static final String object declared in interface and class

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have declared String object inside **interface** which are by default `public`, `static` and `final` . I want to know does it makes any difference in garbage collection in comparison to **class** in which the same String object declared with `public`, `static` and `final`

```
interface Message {
    String SUCCESS = "Request processed successfully";
    String ERROR = "Error in processing your request";
}

class Message {
    public static final String SUCCESS = "Request processed successfully";
    public static final String ERROR = "Error in processing your request";
}
```

Comment: Variables aren't garbage-collected, so it is irrelevant where they are defined. *Objects* are garbage-collected. In this case the only visible objects are pooled string literals. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks i will update title and description

Comment: @EJP i have updated my question

Comment: No difference. You have defined `String` *variables* and their *initial values*. Where the variables are located is irrelevant, for the reason I stated.

Comment: If i use `new String` instead of string literal will it makes any difference ?

Comment: No, there is no difference between interface and class.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks .. for your reply . I asked this question based on the question asked in code review of our project .. The reviewer of our code said using `class` (as stated in above example) will have benefit in garbage collection as compare to `interface` (as stated in above example)

Comment: Using an interface to store constants is an antipattern, but it has nothing to do with GC.

Comment: The reviewer doesn't know what he's talking about. Ask him to support his contention.

Comment: @M.leRutte You are falling into the same trap as the OP. There is no such thing as 'references to the members'.

Comment: @M.leRutte There is still no such thing as 'references to the members', and the behaviour of string literals is completely defined by the JLS, not by the compiler, or by 'specific cases'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables aren't garbage-collected, so it is irrelevant where they are defined. *Objects* are garbage-collected, but in this case the only visible objects are pooled string literals, and the rules for garbage-collecting those are defined by the JLS and the JVM specification; certainly not by whether references to them are defined in classes or interfaces.

Comment: I have a question if i access value of `interface` like this: `Message.SUCCESS` and the `class` in same way, does `interface` has less memory consumption as compare to class `class`. is there any anonymous string object created and they get garbage collected in case with `interface` and not with the `class`.

Comment: 1. No. 2. No. 3. No.

Comment: @AjitSoman: these are *compile-time constants*. When you access `WhatEver.SUCCESS`, it doesn’t matter whether `WhatEver` is a class or interface, the access will get replaced by a direct use of the `String` instance, which will always be the same for a compile-time constant of the same contents. At runtime, such a non-access will not even cause the loading of `WhatEver`, so it might be possible that the variable `SUCCESS` does not even exist in the JVM’s memory. The actual `String` instance `"Request processed successfully"` will exist from the first use through the entire lifetime of the JVM.

Comment: @Holger . Thanks for this awesome explanation. It would be better if you could post this comment as an answer

Comment: @Holger All class constants are loaded when the class is initialized. See [JVM Specification #5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.1).

Comment: @AjitSoman I have already answered your first comment/question above. In my answer.

Comment: @EJP: correct, but as [§12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) states, a class is initialized, when “*A `static` field declared by `T` is used and the field is **not** a constant variable*”. It’s also obvious from a technical view, as each access to the constant is replaced by a direct use of the constant value, without even containing a reference to the holding class, hence, it can’t trigger its class initialization. So in case there isn’t any other trigger for the class initialization, the variables do not exist at runtime.

Comment: @AjitSoman: the comment is only an addition to the answer. As EJP already said, the *variables* do not matter and the fact that you won’t notice whether they exist at runtime, just illustrates this fact. All that matters, are the *objects*, i.e. these two string instances. As the answer already states.